# UIWebView scrollView in iOS 4 doesn't call contentOffset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I had the following code that sets the contentInset for UIWebView's scrollView

```
webScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

and here's how I get the UIWebView scrollView:

```
 - (UIScrollView *)defaultScrollView {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;

        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        if ([currSysVer compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
            return self.scrollView;
        }
        else {
            for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
                if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                    scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
                }
            }

            if (scrollView == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn’t get default scrollview!");
            }
        }
        return scrollView;
    }
```

In iOS 5 calling the above also sets the contentOffset, I know this because it calls the scrollViewDidScroll delegate, however in iOS 4, it doesn't... any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: `scrollViewDidScroll` gets called, when you set the insets (in ios5)? I dont think that should happen..!?

Comment: The offset stays at the same value, regardless of the insets. (eg 0, if not changed yet)

Comment: @jaydee3 yes, that is correct.. I removed the setContentInset and it did not call scrollViewDidScroll on iOS 5.. however on iOS 4 it never calls scrollViewDidScroll when setting content inset, is this apple's bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I tested it in the simulator in iOS 4 AND iOS 5. As soon as I set the insets, the delegate gets called in both OS versions.

The documentation of the delegate tells us:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

// Tells the delegate when the user scrolls the content view within the receiver.
// The delegate typically implements this method to obtain the change in
// content offset from scrollView and draw the affected portion of the content view.
```

First it says **when the user scrolls**, which isn't the case. But in detail it says **change in content offset**, which happens, when you set an inset. Because the content won't change in position, when you set a contentinset, so it corrects the offset correspondingly.

So it's not a bug. But the delegate should be called. In my test - it did.

OK my complete test: The only difference between 4.0 and 5.0, that I see, is that the ScrollView is a `_UIWebViewScrollView` in 5.0. Also the webview-scrollview behaves different from a standard-scrollview. In a standard scrollView the delegate GETS called, in the webviewScrollView it GETS NOT called.

Complete test code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];    


    NSLog(@"System: %@, iOS %@",
          [UIDevice currentDevice].systemName,
          [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);

    UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview: webView];

    UIScrollView* scrollView = [self getScrollViewFromWebView: webView];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"%@", scrollView);

    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"inset: %.1f", scrollView.contentInset.top);
    [scrollView setContentInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)];
    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"inset: %.1f", scrollView.contentInset.top);

    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(20, 20) animated: NO];
    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);



    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 240, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"%@", scrollView);

    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"inset: %.1f", scrollView.contentInset.top);
    [scrollView setContentInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)];
    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"inset: %.1f", scrollView.contentInset.top);

    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(20, 20) animated: NO];
    NSLog(@"offset: %.1f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}

- (UIScrollView *)getScrollViewFromWebView: (UIWebView*) webView {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;

    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return webView.scrollView;
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *subview in [webView subviews]) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            }
        }

        if (scrollView == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn’t get default scrollview!");
        }
    }
    return scrollView;
}
```

Resulting Log for *iOS 4.0*:

```
2012-03-14 18:57:17.943 Test[9009:40b] System: iPhone OS, iOS 4.0.2

2012-03-14 18:57:17.970 Test[9009:40b] <UIScrollView: 0x5e12610; frame = (0 0; 200 200); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5e127f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-03-14 18:57:17.971 Test[9009:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.971 Test[9009:40b] inset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.972 Test[9009:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.972 Test[9009:40b] inset: 44.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.972 Test[9009:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:57:17.973 Test[9009:40b] offset: 20.0

2012-03-14 18:57:17.973 Test[9009:40b] <UIScrollView: 0x5e14c50; frame = (20 240; 200 200); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x5e14240>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-03-14 18:57:17.974 Test[9009:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.974 Test[9009:40b] inset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.974 Test[9009:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:57:17.975 Test[9009:40b] offset: -44.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.975 Test[9009:40b] inset: 44.0
2012-03-14 18:57:17.976 Test[9009:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:57:17.976 Test[9009:40b] offset: 20.0
2012-03-14 18:57:18.468 Test[9009:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:57:19.033 Test[9009:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
```

Resulting Log for *iOS 5.0*:

```
2012-03-14 18:59:08.210 Test[9071:40b] System: iPhone OS, iOS 5.0

2012-03-14 18:59:08.227 Test[9071:40b] <_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x6829020; frame = (0 0; 200 200); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6829230>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-03-14 18:59:08.227 Test[9071:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.228 Test[9071:40b] inset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.228 Test[9071:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.229 Test[9071:40b] inset: 44.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.229 Test[9071:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:59:08.230 Test[9071:40b] offset: 20.0

2012-03-14 18:59:08.230 Test[9071:40b] <UIScrollView: 0xca217a0; frame = (20 240; 200 200); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xca0c880>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-03-14 18:59:08.231 Test[9071:40b] offset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.231 Test[9071:40b] inset: 0.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.232 Test[9071:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:59:08.232 Test[9071:40b] offset: -44.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.232 Test[9071:40b] inset: 44.0
2012-03-14 18:59:08.233 Test[9071:40b] scrollViewDidScroll
2012-03-14 18:59:08.233 Test[9071:40b] offset: 20.0
```

Comment: so how did you set the delegate for the UIScrollView of the UIWebView? Can you show us some of your code snippet?

Comment: sry, i tested with a standard scrollview before. but still no differences betweeng iOS 4 & 5..